# Определить, похожи ли 2 цвета RGB

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

у меня возник одна проблема. У меня есть один массив нужных мне Color32 и я получаю определённый Color32 и мне нужно этот цвет проверить на то, похож ли он на один из элементов массива. Были задумки сделать проверку каждого параметра rgb с каким-то заданным диапазоном, но показалось, что будет не очень корректно и подумал, что есть более разумное решение данного вопроса. Может у кого есть решения с реализацией подобного типа сравнения переменных. Любая помощь пригодится. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Вряд ли вы найдете алгоритм на сравнение "похожести" цветов) ведь у всех своё понятие о их "похожести".

Comment: @M.Green что мешает представить цвета как вектора и просто сравнить их расстояние с какой-то необходимой константой?